# Search for file in IPFS by its filename?

Tags: p2p, ipfs

Is there a way to search for files in IPFS by its filename? If I want for example search for a subject in IPFS, I suppose this subject is in the filename like **some-subject.pdf**, then, there is a way to retrieve the hashes of the files containing the word "subject"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no API to query directly, as bcolin wrote in their answer, but someone is trying to make a search engine and tries to index documents found on IPFS.
The project *IPFSearch* is still in early beta at the time of writing but it can be found here:

**/ipns/ipfsearch.xyz** (untested by me)
or **/ipns/QmSE8g9k5JS1vJ7y5znhSZikmybvdsm3yDj7sbKjPRqsJW** (untested by me)

or, since the DHT is [still super slow](https://github.com/libp2p/go-libp2p-kad-dht/issues/88), through the gateway: https://ipfsearch.xyz

The [announcement](https://discuss.ipfs.io/t/decentralized-search-using-ipfs/2780) was done on discuss.ipfs.io
The project Github is [here](https://github.com/tensojka/ipfsearch-webapp).

Good luck!

Comment: `ipfsearch.xyz` is down

Answer (score 6):

No such thing exists in IPFS, and it's not something that could be implemented int he future because IPFS adresses each file by its hash. If you knew about the existence of a file on IPFS, then you'd have to download it (by adressing it using its hash) to know about its name.

Think about IPFS the same way you'd think about HTTP, but decentralized. It takes Google and its pagerank algorithm to search things on a HTTP-based web, and it'd probably the same with IPFS.